# TexturePackager export to Cocos2d existing sprite sheet

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I got an existing sprite sheet dividing images on a 6x6 matrix. Now I would like to use that on my Cocos2d project. However CCSpriteFrameCache needs a .plist file in order to use them later on a batch node. So the question is how could I generate a .plist file containing the Cocos2d metadata in order to render correctly the sprite sheet. Can this be done using Texture Packager?.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texture Packer does not have this feature.

You could write a script that would generate the plist yourself, the syntax is very easy.

You could also quickly slice them up in Photoshop or something similar and put those images through Texture Packer.